# FindMinimum::ivar: X' is not a valid variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am unable to use FindMinimum nor NMinimize. It gives me "FindMinimum::ivar: X' is not a valid variable." where X is some number in the initial point that I use for the variable. Is my way of assigning values to A and B correct?

Also, is there a more efficient way to force A to be lower trianglar matrix rather than just adding individual constraints?

```
n = 3;
u = ConstantArray[1, n];
B = Array[b, {n, 1}];
(*A=LowerTriangularize[Array[a,{n,n}]]*)
A = Array[a, {n, n}]
x = A . u;
A0 = {{1.964888535199277, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.157613081677548, 
   0.485375648722841, 0.0}, {0.970592781760616, 3.800280468888800, 
   2.915735525189067}}
B0 = {0.792207329559554, 2.959492426392903, 0.485375638722841};
eqs = {Transpose[B] . u - 1, Transpose[B] . x - 1/2, 
   Transpose[B] . x^2 - 1/3, Transpose[B] . A . x - 1/6};
LT = {A[[1, 2]] == 0, A[[1, 3]] == 0, A[[2, 3]] == 0};
vars = {{A, A0}, {B, B0}}
costFunc = Total[eqs^2];

FindMinimum[{costFunc, LT}, Flatten[vars]]
```

> FindMinimum::ivar: 1.964888535199277` is not a valid variable.

```
NMinimize[{costFunc, LT}, Flatten[vars], MaxIterations -> 100]
```

> NMinimize::ivar: 1.964888535199277` is not a valid variable.

Comment: Try `vars = Join[Flatten[{A, A0}, {2, 3}], Transpose[{Flatten@B, B0}]]` and do not `Flatten[vars]`.

Comment: Thanks. Using **FindMinimum[{costFunc, LT}, vars]** solved the problem of assigning initial values. However, the LT constraint is still causing trouble. Any idea on how to force A to be Lower triangular?

Comment: What is the exprssion of `LT`?

Comment: Sorry it got deleted somehow. I have added it

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to use`B = Array[b, n];` instead of `B = Array[b, {n, 1}];` and use the comment by @MichaelE2.

```
n = 3;
u = ConstantArray[1, n];
B = Array[b, n];
A = Array[a, {n, n}]
x = A . u;
A0 = {{1.964888535199277, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.157613081677548, 
   0.485375648722841, 0.0}, {0.970592781760616, 3.800280468888800, 
   2.915735525189067}}
B0 = {0.792207329559554, 2.959492426392903, 0.485375638722841};
eqs = {Transpose[B] . u - 1, Transpose[B] . x - 1/2, 
   Transpose[B] . x^2 - 1/3, Transpose[B] . A . x - 1/6};
LT = {A[[1, 2]] == 0, A[[1, 3]] == 0, A[[2, 3]] == 0};
costFunc = Total[eqs^2];
vars = Join[Transpose@{Flatten[A], Flatten[A0]}, Transpose@{B, B0}]
FindMinimum[{costFunc, LT}, vars]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! **FindMinimum[]** works. Why doesn't this work with **NMinimize[]**, although it accept the same input format as **FindMinimum[]**? Trying **NMinimize[{costFunc, LT}, vars]** gives the error: "....... should be a list of variables, with each element being a variable, or \
a list containing a variable and lower and upper bounds for the
starting region for that variable." Any idea?

Comment: @Morcus  Maybe need to add another conditions and set the format of variables, for example `NMaximize[{costFunc, LT, 0 <= Flatten[A] <= 1, 0 <= B <= 1}, 
 Join[Flatten[A], B]]`